# OS X Keychain access using C/C++

Tags: c++, c, macos, keychain

I am trying to write a simple test application to access OS X keychain. Add/Update/Delete an entry using C/C++. I am just testing whether I can use this in a larger C/C++ code base that we have, where we need a secure secret storage, hence the language requirements.

I looked up the API that Apple has on this but that is mostly in Objective-C. Are there any solutions anyone is aware of? The only thing I could find was [Apple's Security tool](https://opensource.apple.com/source/SecurityTool/SecurityTool-55002/) which seems old and am not sure if the APIs are still supported.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm unclear on what you're asking.  Are you looking for sample code, or just the APIs?  `SecKeychainAddGenericPassword`, for example, is a C API.

Comment: Your security tool example is indeed old, but the keychain API on macOS is old. It's still supported. It's a C API. Apple have an archived code sample on their documentation called `GenericKeychain` but at some point it got ported to swift. If you drill into the [keychain services](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/keychain_items?language=objc) documentation, you'll see it's all C...

Comment: @JWWalker I was looking for code references using the C APIs or any kind of examples. The one that you pointed out seems to be an Objective C API on searching. Apart from the tool I mentioned I couldn't find anything. I had basic questions regarding this, what libs to link against, what right headers to include, the tool is old and just dumps out code. I working example would have definitely helped.

Comment: @TheNextman I have been looking into the keychain services, seems everything has been ported to Objective C. I am trying to quickly understand Objective C basics and write a short sample code that does what I am trying to do. I will try to see if there is a good way to mix Obj C code with the traditional C/C++ code base.

Comment: @harshc you seem to be confused, Keychain Services is C. The `SecKeychainAddGenericPassword` function mentioned is a C function. There is no Objective C involved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A minimal example showing how to add a password to the keychain using C:

```
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
#include <Security/Security.h>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    CFStringRef keys[3];
    keys[0] = kSecClass;
    keys[1] = kSecAttrAccount;
    keys[2] = kSecValueData;

    CFTypeRef values[3];
    values[0] = kSecClassGenericPassword;
    values[1] = CFSTR("accountname");
    values[2] = CFSTR("password");

    CFDictionaryRef query;
    query = CFDictionaryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, (const void**) keys, (const void**) values, 3, NULL, NULL);

    OSStatus result = SecItemAdd(query, NULL);

    printf("%d", result);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks @TheNextman. There was indeed some confusion and lack of understanding. I am a bit wiser than yesterday. I did not use your code, but it nudged me to look in the right direction. Thank you.