# EXC_BAD_ACCESS While trying to access OS X Keychain

Tags: c, xcode, macos, security, keychain

I wrote a sample code (with [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58828239/os-x-keychain-access-using-c-c) received earlier) to add and retrieve a password from OS X keychain. I am able to successfully add the password but when I try to retrieve it I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT). I tried doing this two ways:

1. Using the SecItemCopyMatching API that uses a query based approach to access the keychain.
2. Using the SecKeychainFindGenericPassword.

The BAD ACCESS error happens only withe first approach, the second one succeeds. I am trying to use the first approach so that I can ensure that I am using the *SecKeychainItemFreeContent* to clean up once I am done.

Note - this is a sample code and hence I haven't put any checks for return values. Though I have been keeping an eye on them in the debugger and see no errors there.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
#include <Security/Security.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char acc_name[20];
    char password[20];
    CFStringRef keys[3];

    printf("Enter account name - ");
    scanf("%s", acc_name);

    printf("\nEnter password - ");
    scanf("%s", password);

    keys[0] = kSecClass;
    keys[1] = kSecAttrAccount;
    keys[2] = kSecValueData;

    CFTypeRef values[3];
    values[0] = kSecClassGenericPassword;
    values[1] = CFStringCreateWithCString(kCFAllocatorDefault, acc_name, kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
    values[2] = CFStringCreateWithCString(kCFAllocatorDefault, password, kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

    CFDictionaryRef query;
    query = CFDictionaryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, (const void**) keys, (const void**) values, 3, NULL, NULL);

    OSStatus result = SecItemAdd(query, NULL);

    printf("%d\n", result);

    printf("Retrieve\n");

    SecKeychainItemRef pitem = NULL;
    SecKeychainItemRef kch_ref = NULL;
    CFStringRef qkeys[6];
    qkeys[0] = kSecClass;
    qkeys[1] = kSecAttrAccount;
    qkeys[2] = kSecMatchLimit;
    qkeys[3] = kSecReturnAttributes;
    qkeys[4] = kSecReturnData;
    qkeys[5] = kSecReturnRef;

    CFTypeRef qvalues[6];
    qvalues[0] = kSecClassGenericPassword;
    qvalues[1] = CFStringCreateWithCString(kCFAllocatorDefault, acc_name, kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
    qvalues[2] = kSecMatchLimitOne;
    qvalues[3] = kCFBooleanTrue;
    qvalues[4] = kCFBooleanTrue;
    qvalues[5] = kCFBooleanTrue;

    unsigned int plength = 0;
    char *pdata = NULL;

    unsigned int plength2 = 0;
    void *pdata2 = NULL;

    CFDictionaryRef extract_query = CFDictionaryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, (const void **)qkeys, (const void **)qvalues, 6, NULL, NULL);
    result = SecItemCopyMatching(extract_query, (CFTypeRef *)&kch_ref);
    SecKeychainItemCopyAttributesAndData(kch_ref, NULL, NULL, NULL, &plength2, &pdata2); // <-- EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT) 

    //result = SecKeychainFindGenericPassword(NULL, 0, NULL, (uint32)strlen(acc_name), acc_name, &plength, (void **)&pdata, &pitem);
    if (result)
    {
        //return error;
    }

    printf("password - %s\n", pdata);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be passing a bad parameter to `SecKeychainItemCopyAttributesAndData`.

In your query dictionary, you specify three different return types: `kSecReturnAttributes`, `kSecReturnData`, and `kSecReturnRef`. The documentation for `SecItemCopyMatching` has this to say:

> Use the keys found in Item Return Result Keys to indicate whether you seek the item’s attributes, the item’s data, a reference to the data, a persistent reference to the data, or a combination of these. When you specify more than one return type, the search returns a dictionary containing each of the types you request. When your search allows multiple results, they’re all returned together in an array of items.

So, the type returned by `SecItemCopyMatching` (since you limit to one result) will be a `CFDictionary` containing the item data, item attributes and a reference to the item.

You then pass it to `SecKeychainItemCopyAttributesAndData`, but the documentation for the first parameter says:

> *itemRef*
>
> A reference to the keychain item from which you wish to retrieve data or attributes.

If you modify your query dictionary to only include the `kSecReturnRef` return type (removing `kSecReturnAttributes` and `kSecReturnData`), your code will work.

(Or, extract the reference from the dictionary that `SecItemCopyMatching` is returning and pass *that* to `SecKeychainItemCopyAttributesAndData`)